# Why are numpy array called homogeneous?

Tags: numpy, types

Why are numpy arrays called homogeneous when you can have elements of different type in the same numpy array like this?

np.array([1,2,3,4,"a"])

I understand that I cannot perform some types of broadcasting operations like I cannot perform
np1*4 here and it results in an error.
but my question really is when it can have elements of different types, why it is called homogeneous?

Comment: If you set `x = np.array([1,2,3,4,"a"])` and then inspect `x`, you'll see that it is `array(['1', '2', '3', '4', 'a'], dtype='<U21')`.  All the values have been converted to Unicode strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy automatically converts them to most applicable datatype.

*e.g.,*

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,"a"]).dtype.type
numpy.str_
```

In short this means all elements are of string.

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4]).dtype.type
numpy.int64
```